# Internationalized I18n URL helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Is it possible to have URL helpers in Rails behave differently for different locales, eg.

```
<%= link_to "Something", example_path %>
```

in English would go to **site.com/something**, and in another language to **site.com/lang/blahblah**

Currently, my routes are defined like

```
scope '(:locale)', :locale => /otherlang/ do
    get '/' => 'home#show'
    get 'otherlang-about' => 'about#show'
    get 'otherlang-something/:id' => 'example#show'
end

get 'about' => 'about#show'
get 'something/:id' => 'example#show'

root 'home#show'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, We are using this gem https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator in my company to get different routes_url for each languages but still pointing to the same controller#method.

You just need to define a route.yml file to define the translation for each routes.

Comment: Is it possible to have same routes_url pointing to the same controller controller#method, but only giving different URLs?